# Prevent adding multiple row on single ID

Tags: php, sql

I looking for a way to prevent inserting the `user_id` twice on the single `tc_id` in **Table 2** using PHP or Sql.

**current results:**

**Table 1:**

```
+--------------+
| tc_id | code | 
+--------------+
|   1   |dxcs  |
+--------------+
|   2   |cfgt  |
+--------------+
|   3   |7dhs  |
+--------------+
```

**Table 2:**

```
+--------------------------+
| task_id | tc_id| user_id |
+--------------------------+
|   1     |  2   |   13    |
+--------------------------+
|   2     |  2   |   13    |
+--------------------------+
|   3     |  2   |   18    |
+--------------------------+
|   4     |  3   |   13    |
+--------------------------+
```

In the above `Table 2`, I wanted to insert only 1 `user_id` per `tc_id`. Here you can see above there is 2 `user_id`(13) exist on the single `tc_id`(2). Is there nay SQL way or PHP what to do that?

**expected result:**

**Table 1:**

```
+--------------+
| tc_id | code | 
+--------------+
|   1   |dxcs  |
+--------------+
|   2   |cfgt  |
+--------------+
|   3   |7dhs  |
+--------------+
```

**Table 2:**

```
+--------------------------+
| task_id | tc_id| user_id |
+--------------------------+
|   1     |  2   |   13    |
+--------------------------+
|   2     |  2   |   18    |
+--------------------------+
|   3     |  3   |   13    |
+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Share your code where you're doing the insert...

Comment: Yes, you can do that directly in SQL - by creating a combined UNIQUE INDEX over these two columns. Any attempt to insert a record that would violate this unique index would be rejected, and get you an error message saying so. You didn’t mention which database you are using, for MySQL you can find a basic explanation here, http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/

Comment: Yes, i am using Mysql,  can you spread more light on directly in SQL(UNIQUE index)?

Comment: Check the article I linked to. If you need more “light” on anything in particular, please try to ask more specifically.

Comment: In PHP you can use isset to see if a variable already contains a specific value, however in SQL you can simply say "WHERE field <> 'value'

Answer (score 0):

You can make your column `unqiue`.

```
ALTER TABLE `yourtable` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`col1`, `col2`);

or

ALTER TABLE `yourtable` ADD UNIQUE KEY `unique_index`(`col1`, `col2`);
```

This will make your combination of 2 columns unique so no entry is going to be duplicate if having same values.